# Unwrap and decrypt using crypto.subtle with a NodeJS-generated private key

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes, rsa

I'm generating a key pair on the server like this:

```
crypto.generateKeyPair('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'spki',
        format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs8',
        format: 'pem',
        cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
        passphrase: password,
    }
}, callback);
```

I want to use this key on the client. What I tried is

```
function pad(arr, blocksize) {
    if (arr.length % blocksize === 0) return arr;
    let res = new Uint8Array(Math.floor(arr.length / blocksize) * blocksize + blocksize);
    res.set(arr, 0);
    for (let i = arr.length; i < res.length; i++) {
        res[i] = res.length - arr.length;
    }
    return res;
}

let ek = privateKey;
let h = "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
let f = "\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
ek = atob(ek.substring(h.length, ek.length - f.length).split("\n").join(""));
ek = Uint8Array.from(ek, c => c.charCodeAt(0));
let pwd = password;
pwd = Uint8Array.from(pwd, c => c.charCodeAt(0));
let padded = pad(pwd, 32);
let pwdKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    padded,
    {
        name: "AES-CBC",
        length: 256
    },
    false, ["unwrapKey"]
);
console.log(pwdKey);
let unwrapped = await crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
    "pkcs8",
    ek,
    pwdKey,
    {
        name: "AES-CBC",
        length: 256,
        iv: crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16))
    },
    {
        name: "RSA-PSS",
        hash: "SHA-512",
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        modulusLength: 4096
    },
    false, ["decrypt"]
);
console.log(unwrapped);
```

I also tried padding the private key, it didn't work.

But unwrapping fails with DOMException and no explanation. Any ideas as to how to make it work?

Comment: It looks like NodeJS crypto uses PBKDF2 with an iteration count of 1 (not sure about the hash algorithm yet, and I got to go). However, as long as you provide a "raw" key in subtle, it will likely not work. NodeJS seems to be missing documentation on that particular subject :|

Comment: `generateKeyPair` points to `keyObject.export` which simply documents: "`cipher: <string>` If specified, the private key will be encrypted with the given cipher **and passphrase using PKCS#5 v2.0 password based encryption.**". No talk about configuration parameters, but I surmise that they use PBKDF2 from the source code on GitHub.

Comment: To my knowledge WebCrypto doesn't support encrypted PKCS#8 keys. Nevertheless, such a key can be decrypted in principle, since all required data like salt, digest, iteration count, IV and ciphertext are contained in the (ASN.1 DER) encoded key and can be read with an ASN.1 parser. However, since WebCrypto is a low level API, it doesn't support ASN.1 parsing, so another library would have to be used for that. Once the data has been obtained (which is probably the biggest effort), WebCrypto can be used to first derive the key (via PBKDF2, s. previous comment) and then perform the decryption.